# Why link numbers are different?

Tags: javascript

I tried to count links within a page using JS, but got different results. Why there is a difference?

```js
var intLNK = document.links.length;
console.log(intLNK);

var intA = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
console.log(intA);
```

Comment: [`The links property returns a collection of all <area> elements and <a> elements in a document with a value for the href attribute.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links)

> The links property returns a collection of all `<area>` elements and `<a>` elements in a document with a value for the `href` attribute.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
```

will return the anchor elements irrespective of `href` attribute. You may use

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').length
```

to get the number of anchors having `href` attribute.

If you're interested in performance of two see https://jsperf.com/document-links-vs-document-queryselectorall-a<sup>Thanks to Robert Weber</sup>

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("a[href]").length returned 0 for me, is it tested?

Comment: @k102 No. There was problem, `getElementsByTagName` does not accept attribute selectors. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @k102: Probably should be querySelectorAll().

Answer (score 2):

`document.links` lists those `a` (and `<area>`) which have a `href` attribute, and your selector not - that's the difference.

More [here (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links)

Answer (score 1):

Because some of the anchor `a` tag missing `href` attribute

Answer (score 1):

A tag used for two purpose in HTML.

1) Tagging a location in a document.
   `<A Name = "Section1"> ... </A>`

2) Making a hyperlink reference to another document or Tag.
   `< A HREF = "target location"> ... </A>`

`document.links.length` will return count of Tags with **HREF** attribute, while `document.getElementsByTagName("a").length` will return count of all A tags no matter link or Not.

That's why the output is different.

Answer (score 0):

It's because firsts you're looking for all href values but later your looking for all anchor tags. That's why the results are different

If you want to get all the anchor tags with an href in it you can do it with jquery like this

```
$('a[href]').length
```